Weighted Sobolev embedding
Is a know fact that $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset C(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if $s>n/p$ with $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\left\{u\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\colon \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left((1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}\widehat{u}(\xi)\right)\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\right\}$.
If $w$ is  a weight (measurable locally integrable and nonnegative function) and define $H_w^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\left\{u\in L_w^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\colon \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left((1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}\widehat{u}(\xi)\right)\in L_w^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\right\}$. Is there a similar result about weighted Sobolev spaces?  $H_w^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset C(\mathbb{R}^n\cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$?
